# Django admin: redirect to object change page if only one exists in list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django for an application, and wondering about an option in the admin.
Is it possible for django admin to redirect to the details page of an object, if only one exists in the list view?

For example,
if only this object exists:
[image]

redirect immediately to the change view on this object, without needing the user to click on the object.

I'm not using any custom view. I couldn't find any solution after 2 hours of search.

Thanks!

Comment: You can override [`ModelAdmin.changelist_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view). In there, check if only one object exists for the given model. If yes, then redirect to it's change page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if self.model.objects.all().count() == 1:
        obj = self.model.objects.all()[0]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" %(self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name), args=(obj.id,)))
    return super(ItemAdmin, self).changelist_view(request=request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Also check `changelist_view` parameters based on django version.

Comment: Thanks! With a bit of customization, it solved my issue!